# Show a uiview between 2 buttons when first button is clicked

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uiview

I have two buttons when I press button1, I want to show a uiview between two buttons and the button2 should move downward making space for the view above.
What approach should be used to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: A UIStackView would be a nice fit here

Comment: will the buttons size readjust or the stackview will adjust height according to the content inside?

Comment: UIStackView will adjust based on the content. Using the hidden parameter you can add/remove elements (they are not removed just not visible to the user), which will trigger the resizing. See @Sh_Khan answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a vertical `UIStackView` with 3 items

```
topButton
middleView
bottomButton
```

setting `middleView.isHiddenn = false` will show it with it's size and `middleView.isHiddenn = true` will completely collapse it

Comment: did the same. Set the stacview Distribution to equal spacing but its not working as aspection the middle view is not showing

Comment: make it fill instead of equal spacing and give the middleView a height if it has no intrinsic content size